# OpenLayers 3: Change drawing style, but keep style of previously drawn features

Tags: openlayers, symbology, digitizing

I created a vector and a drawing interaction:

```
// Create feature collection and vector
var featureCollection = new ol.Collection();
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: featureCollection
});
featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 0.5'
        })
    })
});
featureOverlay.setMap(map);


// create drawing interaction
drawingInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureCollection,
    type: 'Polygon'
});

map.addInteraction(drawingInteraction);
```

Now I would like to let a user change the drawing style, which, when called separately, can be done like this:

```
var s = new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5'
            })
});

featureOverlay.setStyle(s);
```

This works fine, but it changes the style of *all* the drawn polygons. However, I would like to change the *new* ones only and keep the styling of the existing ones.

For example, I draw my initial red polygons:

[image]

Then the user switches styles by firing the setStyle() method above, but then all polygons turn green, not just the one I will set after firing the method and drawing a new polygon:

[image]

Comment: It will be a little more tricky, but it can be accomplished. You have to set the style of the feature instead of the layer.

Comment: That helped me solve it! I posted the code below! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Gabor Farkas I was able to fix the issue. The style should not be set on the vector but on the *single feature*, that will be drawn.

This can be done by setting the feature's style once drawing begins:

```
drawingInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureCollection,
    type: geomType
});

drawingInteraction.on('drawstart',function(event){
    var s = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: drawingPolyStyle.colors
        })
    });

    event.feature.setStyle(s);

});

map.addInteraction(drawingInteraction);
```

In the example drawingPolyStyle is an object that holds the colors that were chosen in a color picker menu.