# OpenLayers 3: Digitizing holes (donut polygons)

Tags: openlayers, digitizing, donut-polygons, holes

I am working on an OpenLayers 3 digitizing tool, which works very fine [at this point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219343/openlayers-3-change-drawing-style-but-keep-style-of-previously-drawn-features/219348#219348).

I would like to add a functionality that lets me add holes to existing polygons.

I know this is doable in OpenLayers 2, as you can see [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/donut.html):

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same effect in OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported out of the box by the library. There is an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3287) on its GitHub project page marked with PR accepted. However, this problem can be solved without this capability and the result might be even more robust. I'm planning to make a digitizing software as well in the future, and I would mimic the QGIS approach at this point.

In QGIS, you can only draw polygons by default. However, there is a dedicated tool for drawing rings. It is fully automatic, thus if you activate that tool, you get a drawing interaction just like the one you draw your polygons with. After you finished the ring, the software decides if it can form a valid ring of an existing polygon (e.g. no intersects), and if it can, it punches the ring into the polygon. BTW, you can check if a polygon is completely inside another one by calling the [`intersectsCoordinate`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#intersectsCoordinate) method of the outer ring with every coordinate of the hole. A little bit clumsy for my taste, but if you don't want to write or adapt an algorithm for checking intersections between polygons, it's working.

- Pro:

  - This method is fully automatic.
- Contra:

  - The feature order decides the chosen polygon, if there are more than one valid host for the given ring.

Because of the contra, I would alter QGIS's method, and require the user to select a polygon prior to making the "ring puncher" drawing tool active.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I might have to develop my own functionality. Is there a way to erase a newly drawn geometry from another one? Maybe I could use that logic then. Btw, your book is helping me a lot :-)